# How to pass GraphQL query result as a prop to another component - react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a wrapper which queries a mongodb collection for a document ID based on a `teamName` parameter.  I'd like to pass this document ID to another component.  I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.  Here's what I have so far:

wrapper:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

export const GET_TEAM_REGISTRATION_ID = gql`
    query($teamName: String!) {
        getTeamRegistrationID(teamName: $teamName) {
            _id
        }
    }
`;

const withTeamRegistrationID = Component => props => {

    return (
        <Query query={GET_TEAM_REGISTRATION_ID}>
            {({ loading, data }) => {

                return (
                    <Component getTeamRegistrationIDLoading={loading} getTeamRegistrationID={data && data.getTeamRegistrationID} {...props} />
                );
            }}
        </Query>
    );
};

export default withTeamRegistrationID;
```

Component:

```
@withTeamRegistrationID
export class FormPlayerDetails extends Component {

    render() { 
        console.log(this.props); 
}
```

I have two questions: 1) How do I pass the `teamName` parameter in the component, and 2) how do I pass the query result as a prop into another component? I'd like to do something like `this.props.getTeamRegistrationID`

Comment: Your query `GET_TEAM_REGISTRATION_ID` receive a variable `teamName`, so have you forgot passing `teamName` in `<Query query={GET_TEAM_REGISTRATION_ID}>...`. I think it should be:
`
<Query query={GET_TEAM_REGISTRATION_ID}>
            {({ loading, data, variables: {teamName: 'abc'} }) => {
               ...
            }}
        </Query>
`